# How to reinforce a Wobbly hipped roof gazebo built on a concrete patio?

Tags: wood

My husband is building a 10x10 hipped roof gazebo by our pool.  It looks great, but the closer he gets to finishing and adding more weight on top with the shingles etc. the shakier it becomes.

It is secured with post brackets into the concrete.  The posts are 6x6.

Is there any way to reinforce the mounted portion to the concrete to reinforce?

Comment: Do you have diagonal braces where the vertical post meets the horizontal beams?

Comment: Has he added any cross bracing or Knee bracing? Photos of the wobbly gazebo will help. We need to know more about how the gazebo is constructed.

Comment: Triangles. Which is shorthand for braces that make things stable, since it's far too late to use ground contact pressure-treated or hybrid laminated posts to get stability from setting the posts in the ground rather than on wobbly post bases. X-braces, knee braces, brackets - all triangles.

Comment: Yes, this sort of structure isn't supported at the concrete. It needs to be independently rigid. Please post photos.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your responses.   He is working on the corner diagonal bracing today.  I still think some sort of angle iron surrounding the vertical posts anchored into the ground and into the beams would be good - just not sure if that sort of thing is available?   I'll get pics!